# Probability question with two teams

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If two teams play a best of 7. (So they win if they win 4 games). If probability of either team winning a game is $\frac{1}{2}$, then what is the probability that the series lasts 7 games? What if the probabilities of winning for $A$ were $P(A) = p \ne \frac{1}{2}$.

For the 0.5 case we just need to count the number of ways to distribute 3 wins and losses over 6 games and divide by $2^7$ correct? So then this is $\frac{20}{32} = \frac{5}{8}$? This sseems a little high.

Comment: The probability should be 5/16, not 5/8. http://mste.illinois.edu/hill/ev/seriessol.html

Answer (score 4):

Note that the series lasts $7$ games if and only if each team wins $3$ times in the first $6$ games; so the probability is $$\binom{6}{3}\cdot{\left (\frac{1}{2}\right )}^{6}$$

If the  probabilities of winning for A were $p$ then the result is $$\binom{6}{3}\cdot p^{3}\cdot (1-p)^{3}$$